# Proving a linear map is surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

> Suppose $V_1, \dots, V_m$ are vector spaces. Prove that
> $\mathcal{L}(V_1 \times \dots \times V_m, W)$ is isomorphic to
> $\mathcal{L}(V_1, W) \times \dots \times \mathcal{L}(V_m, W).$ (Note that $V_{i}$'s can be infinite-dimensional.)

I am having trouble showing that $\varphi$ defined below is surjective. For every $f \in \mathcal{L}(V_1 \times \dots \times V_m, W),$ I defined $f_{i}: V_{i} \to W$ by $$f_{i} (v_{i}) = f (0, \dots, v_{i}, \dots, 0).$$ Then, I defined $\varphi: \mathcal{L}(V_1 \times \dots \times V_m, W) \to \mathcal{L}(V_1, W) \times \dots \times \mathcal{L}(V_m, W)$ by $$\varphi (f) = (f_{1}, \dots, f_{m}).$$

Now, how would I show that $\varphi$ is surjective?
I know I have to show that for any $(g_{1}, \cdots, g_{m}) \in \mathcal{L}(V_1, W) \times \dots \times \mathcal{L}(V_m, W)$, there is a corresponding $g \in \mathcal{L}(V_1 \times \dots \times V_m, W)$ so that $\varphi (g) = (g_{1}, \dots, g_{m}).$
Can I simply define $g \in \mathcal{L}(V_1 \times \dots \times V_m, W)$ by
$$g (0, \dots, v_{i}, \dots, 0) = g_{i} (v_{i})? $$

I am not sure where to start.

Comment: Yes, this is a good start! You can indeed define $g$ this way, but since it's currently unclear to you why, you should instead define $g$ explicitly: tell your reader what $g(v_1, \dots, v_n)$ should be for all $(v_1, \dots, v_n) \in V_1 \times \dots \times V_n$, and prove that the function you defined is linear and that it satisfies $\varphi(g) = (g_1, \dots, g_n)$. Side note: of course you will also have to show that $\varphi$ is injective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $(g_1,\dots,g_m) \in \mathcal{L}(V_1,W) \times \cdots \times \mathcal{L}(V_m,W)$ define $g : V_1 \times \cdots \times V_m \to W$ by
$$g(v_1,\dots,v_m) = g_1(v_1) + \cdots + g_m(v_m).$$

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! Please let me know if this is the correct understanding following your definition of $g$: by defining such $g$, (after showing $g$ linear) we can apply $\varphi$ to $g$ and obtain $\varphi (g) = (g_{1}, \dots, g_{m})$. This shows that $\textrm{range } \varphi = \mathcal{L}(V_1, W) \times \dots \times \mathcal{L}(V_m, W)$.

Comment: That is correct. Also, you can define $\psi : \mathcal{L}(V_1,W) \times \cdots \times \mathcal{L}(V_m,W) \to \mathcal{L}(V_1 \times \cdots \times V_m,W)$ by $\psi(g_1,\dots,g_m)(v_1,\dots,v_m) = g_1(v_1) + \cdots + g_m(v_m)$, and notice that $\psi = \varphi^{-1}$. This avoids having to check the injectivity and surjectivity.